# Unable to pull in contents of a div into another

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pull in the contents of one div into another. Here's my code:

```
<script>
(function($) {

    region = ivalue_1[selectedRegion];

    document.getElementById('block1').innerHTML = region;   

    var distributor = document.getElementById('distributor-form');
    document.getElementById('block2').innerHTML = distributor;

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

At the moment the "block2" just displays:

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

I would never do it this way (I'd use jquery) but this code goes within a Wordpress plugin and the only way content will display is by doing something along the lines of `document.getElementById('block1').innerHTML = region;`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where do `ivalue_1` and `selectedRegion` come from?

Comment: `document.getElementById('block2').innerHTML = distributor.outerHTML;`

Comment: Every one repeating the same answer! Quite many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var distributor = document.getElementById('distributor-form');
```

should be

```
var distributor = document.getElementById('distributor-form').innerHTML;
```

The first line just returns the complete HTML element as an object. You're only interested in the value within the element

Answer (score 0):

You don't add the HTML-Code but the HTML-Element.
Change your code to:

```
document.getElementById('block2').innerHTML = distributor.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot do get the innerHTML from distributor:

```
document.getElementById('block2').innerHTML = distributor.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed innerHTML

```
 document.getElementById('block2').innerHTML = distributor.innerHTML;
```